# Define map with predicate recursively

Tags: python, recursion

I want to define a map function that maps over elements of a list if the element fulfils a predicate.

My idea is to break the list down to 2 halves and apply the function recursively. The catch base would be when there is only 1 element left in the list, the element would be checked if `prae(element) == True`, True -> `fun(x)` and False -> `pass`. Then i will concatenate the 2 halves to get the final list.

```
def is_odd(n):
  return n%2 == 1

def square(x):
  return x**2

def map_ifr(lis,prae,fun):
  if len(lis) == 1:
      results = [fun(x) for x in lis if prae(x) == True]
  else:
    mid = len(lis)//2
    first_half = lis[:mid]
    second_half = lis[mid:]
    map_ifr(first_half,prae,fun) + map_ifr(second_half,prae,fun)

a = map_ifr([1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 ], is_odd , square )
a
```

i got error that the operand type is `Nonetype`. I'm not sure why this is the case. I ran into problem with `Nonetype` quite often and don't know the real cause of it. Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

You don't return anything from `map_ifr` function, so by default it returns `None` and fails on `map_ifr(first_half,prae,fun) + map_ifr(second_half,prae,fun)` line because `None + None` is not valid operation. Corrected code:

```
def map_ifr(lis, prae, fun):
  if len(lis) == 1:
      results = [x for x in lis if prae(x) == True]
  else:
      mid = len(lis)//2
      first_half = lis[:mid]
      second_half = lis[mid:]
      results = map_ifr(first_half,prae,fun) + map_ifr(second_half,prae,fun)

  return results

a = map_ifr([1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 ], is_odd , square)
print(a)
```

Output:

> [1, 3, 5]

Answer (score 1):

`map_ifr` doesn't return anything. However, in Python it means that it returns `None`. So, here:

```
map_ifr(first_half,prae,fun) + map_ifr(second_half,prae,fun)
```

...you're trying to add `None + None`, which obviously makes zero sense, so you get the error.

Speaking about the base case:

```
if len(lis) == 1:
    results = [x for x in lis if prae(x) == True]
```

This straight up wastes computing power because it builds the list and then throws it right away when the function returns. You should return stuff from your function instead:

```
def map_ifr(lis,prae,fun):
  if len(lis) == 1:
      return [x for x in lis if prae(x) == True]
  else:
    mid = len(lis)//2
    first_half = lis[:mid]
    second_half = lis[mid:]
    return map_ifr(first_half,prae,fun) + map_ifr(second_half,prae,fun)
```